# Why is my TS code not interpreted as CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, module

I use a [dependency](https://github.com/projectstorm/react-diagrams/blob/d2f05438b8620147d7aa835f2799a0f56397d4e3/tsconfig.base.json#L12) which is transpiled to ES6.

I want to use ES2019 features in my own code.

Finally I want to emit ES6.

My attempt at `tsconfig`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "removeComments": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "lib": [
        "es2019",
        "dom"
      ],
      "target":"ES6"
    }
}
```

This compiles, but when loading in browser I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` caused by one of my files. Attempting to solve that I added `"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"` to a .babelrc:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
    ]
}
```

This solves the issue but I don't understand why it is needed. My tsconfig already declares modules as commonjs and the dependency is also using commonjs as specified in its tsconfig(!?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CommonJS` module setting is mainly used for Node applications, as Node uses the commonjs module system. The browser doesn't understand commonjs modules by default, so this is why you get the `exports is not defined` error.

From what I understood, you want to output ES6 modules, so you should use `"module": "ES6"`

Comment: Aha that makes sense! Though if I set compilerOptions.module = "ES6" I get TS2792: Cannot find module 'X' for deps [@projectstorm/react-diagrams, axios, lodash, file-saver]. These are all deps to be consumed typically via browser apps so Im not quit following. Am I missing something else?

Comment: It seems I can use ES6 if I also set property "moduleResolution" to "node"

Comment: Not 100% sure what other options need to be configured, but if changing the `moduleResolution` gets things working for you then that that's good :D

Comment: *"...as Node uses the commonjs module system..."* Node.js now has both CJS and [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Comment: ESM is still experimental in LTS Node though, is it not?